# How to change platform version in Ripple emulator?

Tags: cordova, ripple

How Can I change platform in Ripple emulator from default PhoneGap 2.0.0 to PhoneGap 2.5.0?

I need some features form the latest Phonegap version and I cannot find a way to change version. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little misleading. Ripple actually tries to support the latest version of Cordova, so the version should really say 2.x. We are working on fixing the way we manage platform version.

Short answer, selecting version 2.0.0 should work for you with a 2.5.0 app. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok tnx. The reason why I was asking this is because I get "I haz cheeseburger" alert by calling SplashScreen.hide() which was added in PhoneGap 2.2

Comment: Is there any progress in this area? I'm using Cordova '3.0.0-0-ge670de9' and would like to use it with the Ripple emulator. Thank you! -- Freddy Snijder

Answer (score 2):

Here's the workaround I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  // Wait for Cordova to load
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  // Cordova is ready
  function onDeviceReady() {
    //check if inside ripple wrapper
    if (!document.getElementById('tinyhippos-injected'))
      navigator.splashscreen.hide();
  }
</script>
```

tinyHippos is the company that created Ripple. It was acquired by Blackberry in 2011.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Ripple emulator supports only PhoneGap v 2.0.0 only. You may have to use the iOS emulator to do your testing

Comment: Interesting.. Well, why would they write that they are adding 2.5.0 Cordova support in https://github.com/blackberry/Ripple-UI/blob/master/doc/CHANGELOG.md for version v0.9.14 on March 06?

Comment: They say "Fixed Ripple not working with Cordova 2.5.0" . This does not necessarily mean that all features of 2.5.0 are being supported.